# how to get the sum of group by in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have the following tables:

**Fans**

`id, id_page, number_of_fans, created_at`

This table has many same `id_page` but it differs in `created_at`

**Page**

`id, id_facebook, id_keyword, is_processed (0/1)`

**keyword**

`id, keyword, category`

I am experimenting/trying sub-queries but I didn't get the result that I wanted, sometimes the query is very slow because of its complexity.

I would like the result to:

1. I will get the latest(`created_at`) - (returns only 1 row from table `fans` per page) -  `number_of_fans` in `fans` table by page and get the sum of all `number_of_fans` by group by `keyword`
2. I will get all the pages group by `keyword`
3. I will get all the pages group by `keyword` where `is_processed` = 1

How will it be possible to combine the result of 1, 2, 3 with just 1 query in MySQL?

Thank you.

Regards,
bhadz

Comment: no one can understand this way unless you show sample data and sample output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the [groupwise maximum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html) from the `Fans` table: it can be found from grouping the table by page and selecting the maximum `created_at` value, this is then joined back to the `Fans` table to obtain the other columns from that maximum record:

```
SELECT   Keyword.keyword,
         SUM(Fans.number_of_fans) fans_of_all_pages,
         SUM(IF(Page.is_processed,Fans.number_of_fans,0)) fans_of_processed_pages
FROM     Fans NATURAL JOIN (
           SELECT   id_page, MAX(created_at) AS created_at
           FROM     Fans
           GROUP BY id_page
         ) t
    JOIN Page    ON    Page.id = Fans.id_page
    JOIN Keyword ON Keyword.id = Page.id_keyword
GROUP BY Keyword.id
```

Comment: hi eggyal, thank you for the answer. that is what I'm looking for. 
really appreciated.